# not working in $app->get function in heroku when setup an shopify app

Tags: shopify

am building up an app on heroku for shopify store here is my index.php code 
i want to run different files on different URL it work with \ based url ata that time index.twig file run but when i do some code like this

if we code like that than it will run index.twig but

```
  $app->get('/', function() use($app) {
        $st = $app['pdo']->prepare('SELECT name FROM test_table');
        $st->execute();
    echo 'hi';
        $names = array();
        while ($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $app['monolog   ']->addDebug('Row ' . $row['name']);
            $names[] = $row;
        }

        return $app['twig']->render('index.twig', array(
            'names' => $names
        ));
    });
```

but when we do like this it will giev error

```
$app->get('/db/', function() use($app) {
    $st = $app['pdo']->prepare('SELECT name FROM test_table');
    $st->execute();
echo 'hi';
    $names = array();
    while ($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $app['monolog   ']->addDebug('Row ' . $row['name']);
        $names[] = $row;
    }

    return $app['twig']->render('database.twig', array(
        'names' => $names
    ));
});
```

it will give error 
The requested URL /db/ was not found on this server.

and not run database.twig

please help for this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's out of Shopify scope.

You seem to use some framework for building up the app. Silex maybe?
When you request http://yourdomain.com/db/ it actually tries to find this URL, but there's no such path. That's why you get 404.

Many of the modern frameworks have a front controller index.php which decides what other controller to use to manage your request. Indeed all the request should go to this index.php script.

So you have to pull out http://yourdomain.com/index.php/db/ It should work out. But it contains this script name segment which makes URL looks untidy. You are able to remove it with .htaccess. If my assumption is correct and you are indeed using Silex, consider this: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html